# Air Native Extension + Facebook SDK + FacebookSDKResources.bundle = not working

Tags: ios, xcode, ant, facebook-ios-sdk, air-native-extension

I can't add the resources from FacebookSDKResource.bundle in my ANE project. For exemple, when I open a Facebook dialog(FBDialog.m), there is no close button which is in this bundle. The close button is invisible at the top left without image. FacebookSDK get the image from FacebookSDKResources like this: 
UIImage* closeImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"FacebookSDKResources.bundle/FBDialog/images/close.png"];

All works fine, the dialog opens, but without close button (close.png)
How can I add this bundle in a ANE? I compile in command line with ANT.

Answer (score 0):

You have to explicity import the file FacebookSDKResources.bundle into the Ressources folder in XCode. (copy-paste the file then drag-and-drop it in XCode, add as group)